# Diferença entre extends e include utilizando o Template Engine SWIG

Tags: node.js

Estou utilizando o Template Engine com NodeJS e não consegui compreender a diferença entre usar o extends e o include.
Eu consegui entender que o include você incluí direto um parte do HTML em qualquer lugar, mas não consegui diferenciar do extends.

Alguém poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extends quer dizer que ele vai buscar um pedaço do template e complementa-o, inserindo o código dentro do outro em blocos/sitios prédefenidos.

Includes quer dizer que ele pega um pedaço do template e coloca-o dentro do código.

Há exemplos de ambos no Github ([link](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/tree/master/examples/express/views)), mas coloco aqui também:

#### Extend:

layout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Example</title>


</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
        {% block header %}{% endblock %}
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="/people">People</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section role="main">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}
```

Este exemplo é bem simples. Ao abrir `index.html` ele vai usar o template do `layout.html` e extrendê-lo/acrescentar o texto `Home Page` dentro do `block title` que no `layout.html` está com `<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Example</title>`. Ou seja acrescenta-se ao template.

#### Includes:

form.html

```
{% macro input(type, name, label) %}
<label for="{{ name }}">{{ label }}</label>
<input type="{{ type }}" name="{{ name }}" id="{{ name }}">
{% endmacro %}

{% macro button type label %}
<button type="{{ type|default("submit") }}">{{ label|default("Submit") }}</button>
{% endmacro %}
```

index.html

```
{% import 'form.html' as form %}

<ul>
    <li>{{ form.input("text", "name", "Your Name") }}</li>
    <li>{{ form.input("text", "age", "Your Age") }}</li>
</ul>

{{ form.button() }}
```

Neste caso `index.html` vai buscar um pedaço de código novo, incluíndo-o no seu conteúdo. Não insere nada dentro desse bloco, simplesmente o importa.

Comment: Show de bola Sérgio!
Consegui compreender melhor agora a diferença!

Obrigado!